# C++ Cereal save/load_and_construct not working

Tags: c++, cereal

So I'm trying to use the [Cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/index.html) library and I've come to an issue I can't seem to overcome. Essentially the doc's say it is possible to deserialize [Types with no default constructor](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/pointers.html). Yet in the implementation notes it says `Define a serialize or save/load pair as you normally would` yet the serialize/load options cannot be defined in a valid manner if there is no default constructor. I take this to mean, the `load_and_construct` function takes the place of `load`. Yet when implementing a relatively simple example seen below.

"main.cpp"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

#include <cereal/access.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/string.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/vector.hpp>
#include <cereal/types/memory.hpp>
#include <cereal/archives/portable_binary.hpp>

struct string_wrapper {
    const std::string str;

    string_wrapper(const std::string& _a) : str{_a} {}

    template <class Archive>
    void save(Archive& _archive) const {
        _archive(str);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    static void load_and_construct(Archive& _archive,
        cereal::construct<string_wrapper>& _construct) {
        std::string a;
        _archive(a);
        _construct(a);
    }
};

struct wrapper_of_string_wrappers {
    const std::vector<string_wrapper> strs;

    wrapper_of_string_wrappers(
        const std::vector<string_wrapper>& _a
    ) : strs{_a} { }

    template <class Archive>
    void save(Archive& _archive) const {
        _archive(strs);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    static void load_and_construct(Archive& _archive,
        cereal::construct<wrapper_of_string_wrappers>& _construct) {
        std::vector<string_wrapper> strs;
        _archive(strs);
        _construct(strs);
    }
};


int main() {

    auto file = "test.bin";

    { // save
        std::ofstream os(file, std::ios::binary);
        cereal::PortableBinaryOutputArchive archiveSave(os);

        std::vector<string_wrapper> as;
        as.push_back({"Hello"});
        as.push_back({"World"});

        wrapper_of_string_wrappers test(as);

        auto test_ptr = std::make_unique<wrapper_of_string_wrappers>(test);
        archiveSave(test_ptr);
    }

    { // load
        std::ifstream is(file, std::ios::binary);
        cereal::PortableBinaryInputArchive archiveLoad(is);

        std::unique_ptr<wrapper_of_string_wrappers> test = nullptr;
        archiveLoad(test);
        std::cout << (*test).strs[0].str << " " << (*test).strs[1].str << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This code obviously is kind of pointless, its just a minimal example to illustrate the problem I'm running into.

Comment: I could not reproduce your error with your code with latest cereal code. Which version are you using?

Comment: @miradham 1.2.2, currently the newest available on the official site.

Comment: @miradham I've added additional information to my original post.

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so that others can help you

Comment: @miradham I've rewritten my example code, this gives the exact same behavior and should be easily runnable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page](https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/issues/102)

> Non-default constructors are currently only supported for serializing pointers

Your problem here is you are trying to serialize non pointer values with no default constructor here

```
std::vector<string_wrapper> strs;
_archive(strs);
```

To solve your problem you need either make default constructor for `string_wrapper` with `save/load` pair or use `string_wrapper` as pointer in `wrapper_of_string_wrappers`.

Here is working code for second option(`string_wrapper` remains same):

```
struct wrapper_of_string_wrappers {
    //const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<string_wrapper>> strs;
    //const string_wrapper strs;
    const std::unique_ptr<string_wrapper> strs;

    wrapper_of_string_wrappers(
        //const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<string_wrapper>>& _a
        const string_wrapper _a
    ) : strs{ new string_wrapper(_a) } { }

    wrapper_of_string_wrappers(
        const wrapper_of_string_wrappers& w
    ) : strs{ new string_wrapper(*w.strs) } { }

    template <class Archive>
    void save(Archive& _archive) const {
        _archive(strs);
    }

    template <class Archive>
    static void load_and_construct(Archive& _archive,
        cereal::construct<wrapper_of_string_wrappers>& _construct) {
        //std::vector<std::unique_ptr<string_wrapper>> strs;
        std::unique_ptr<string_wrapper> strs;
        _archive(strs);
        _construct(*strs);
    }
};

int main() {

    auto file = "test.bin";
    { // save
        std::ofstream os(file, std::ios::binary);
        cereal::PortableBinaryOutputArchive archiveSave(os);

        string_wrapper as("Hello");
        wrapper_of_string_wrappers test(as);

        auto test_ptr = std::make_unique<wrapper_of_string_wrappers>(test);
        archiveSave(test_ptr);
    }

    { // load
        std::ifstream is(file, std::ios::binary);
        cereal::PortableBinaryInputArchive archiveLoad(is);
        std::unique_ptr<wrapper_of_string_wrappers> test = nullptr;
        archiveLoad(test);
        std::cout << (*test).strs->str << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that the std::vector would be treated like a pointer so I thought it wouldn't be an issue. Thank you for clarifying this.